# Inc function Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

This may be really simple but when I try to compile a program containing

```pascal
Inc(Count);
```

In Inno Setup I keep getting

> Unknown identifier 'Inc'

I believe this is how you increment integers in Pascal, and am confused on how to proceed here.

I am using Inno Setup 5.5.9(a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `Inc` does not work in Ansi version of Inno Setup. It works in Unicode version though.

You should not use Ansi version anyway. It's 2016, no application should use legacy encoding anymore. Switch to the Unicode version.

---

If you have a very good reason to stick with Ansi version (like lots of Pascal code that works with Ansi strings, which is error prone when converting to Unicode version, see [Upgrading from Ansi to Unicode version of Inno Setup (any disadvantages)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848)), you can of course use:

```pascal
Count := Count + 1;
```